# Beginner - Script recognizing "pi" and "e" and converting them into numbers

Tags: python

I am completely new to any coding at all.

As one of my first little tasks I tried to design a program comparing numbers. I wanted to add a function that distinguishes "pi" and "e" entries and converts them into respective floats. This function, however, doesnt work fine.

```
# the user is prompted to insert a value. This will be stored `enter code here`as "input1"
input1=input("insert a number:")
# decide whether the input is a number or a word. Convert words `enter code here`into numbers:
def convert(pismeno):
    if pismeno == "pi":
    number=float(3.14)
    print ("word pi converted to number:", (number))
  elif pismeno == "e":
    number= float(2.71)
    print ("word e converted to number:", (number))
  else:
   number = float(pismeno)
    print (number, "is already a number. No need to convert.")
# call the convert function onto the input:
convert(input1)
print ("The number you chose is:",input1)*
```

I guess that it has something to do with the output being stored inside the function and not "leaking" outside to the general code. Please keep in mind that I have literally NO experience so stick to a child language rather than the usual professional speech.

Comment: What does "doesn't work fine" entail? errors? invalid results? the indentation in your code doesn't seem correct, please fix it

Comment: Try using it. When I type "pi" or "e" to the input, it says "The number you chose is: pi" instead of "The number you chose is: 3.14"

Comment: If I tried using it, I'd get errors about the indentation. It isn't my responsibility to make sure your [mcve] works

Comment: Please, keep in mind that I am completely new to programming so stick to a child language rather that the usual professional stuff. I came to ask for a help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a function, you need a return statement. A simplified example of your code:

```
def convert(pismeno):
    if pismeno == "pi":
        number=float(3.14)
        print ("word pi converted to number:", number)
        return number
    else:
        ....

....
input1=input("insert a number:")
print(convert(input1))
```

I really suggest you to study basic concepts of programming. You may start here: https://www.learnpython.org/. More about functions: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions

Answer (score 0):

> The number you chose is: pi" instead of "The number you chose is: 3.14"

Your current final print just prints the input you originally gave it (`input1`)

You need to provide a way to return a value from the function and then set that to a variable where you call it

```
def convert(pismeno):
    ... Code ...    
    return number


# call the convert function onto the input:
output_num = convert(input1)
print ("The number you chose is:",output_num )
```